# How to normalize text when computing the word error rate of a speech recognition system?

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, software, speech-recognition

I am looking for a library, script or program that can normalize the transcribed and gold texts when computing the word error rate (WER) of an automated speech recognition system.

For example, if:

- the gold transcript is `Without the dataset the article is useless`
- the predicted transcript is `Without the data set the article's useless`

the texts should be normalized so that the WER is 0 (and not 3 or 4 if the text isn't normalized).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbShQ3
- https://redd.it/7wrgx2

Answer (score 1):

The `hubscr.pl` tool from sclite uses GLM files for normalization, you can dowload an example [here](http://data.cstr.ed.ac.uk/asru/MGB3/scoring/task1scoring.zip) or [here](http://www.iwslt2011.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=dev2010_glm_stm.tgz).

The syntax of GLM files is described [here](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/doc/GLMRules.txt) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319021431/https://github.com/chinshr/sctk/blob/master/doc/GLMRules.txt)).

GLM files are essentially regular expression kind of normalization where you need to list all possible expansions. They aren't generic enough though.

Excerpt from [`en20030506.glm`](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/c903457f3cf72d749e0f73fd7b2625fbbab8a833/egs/ami/s5/local/english.glm)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319022305/https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/master/egs/ami/s5/local/english.glm)):

```
[WINNER'S] => [{WINNER'S / WINNER IS / WINNER HAS}] / [ ] __ [ ]
[WINTER'S] => [{WINTER'S / WINTER IS / WINTER HAS }] / [ ] __ [ ]
[WISCONSIN'S] => [{WISCONSIN'S / WISCONSIN IS / WISCONSIN HAS}] / [ ] __ [ ]
[WIT'S] => [{WIT'S / WIT IS / WIT HAS}] / [ ] __ [ ]
[WOMAN'S] => [{WOMAN'S / WOMAN IS / WOMAN HAS}] / [ ] __ [ ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I can see that dataset -> data set is missing. But still very useful.